# React Router DOM Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Has anyone of you encountered this error when using tree-shaking on react-router-dom?

This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Link from 'react-router-dom/Link';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppBar>
                <Toolbar className="nav-container">
                    <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to={'/'}>Home</Button>
                    <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to={'/signup'}>Signup</Button>
                    <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to={'/login'}>Login</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        )
    }
}
```

And I am receiving an error `` Warning: Please use `require("react-router-dom").Link` instead of `require("react-router-dom/Link")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release. ``

Here are the current version of the web app dependencies.

```
{
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct import is

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```